# Highcarts - Have datetime xaxis start on certain month

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have my xaxis displaying how I want, with a tick interval of every six months. My issue is I am trying to have the label start on march. So instead of the the xaxis displaying "Jan" and "July" I want it to display "March" and "September". Didn't think this would be hard but cant seem to get it.

```
xAxis: {
  type: "datetime",
  tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 180,
  startOnTick: true,
  endOnTick: true,
  showLastLabel: true,
  labels: {
    rotation: -45,
    format: "{value:%b-%y}"
  }
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gsxwpf92/

Answer (score 1):

You will need `tickPositioner` [Reference API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner)

```
...
xAxis: {
  type: "datetime",
  // tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 180, // Overrided by tickPositioner
  startOnTick: true,
  endOnTick: true,
  showLastLabel: true,
  labels: {
    rotation: -45,
    format: "{value:%b-%y}"
  },
  tickPositioner: function () {
    var positions = [],
        tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
        increment = 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 180; // 6 months

    for (tick; tick <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
      positions.push(tick);
    }
    if (positions.indexOf(this.dataMax) == -1) positions.push(this.dataMax);
    return positions;
  }
},
...
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/apb5zq4e/)